# AWS Cognito without Amplify?

Tags: express, authentication, amazon-cognito

I am currently building an app that has a React frontend and express.js backend. I am using @aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider npm library in my backend to login and register new users. For reference below are the methods I use to register new user and login existing users:

```
const registerUser = async ({
  firstName,
  lastName,
  email,
  password,
  phoneNumber,
}) => {
  const attributeList = [];

  attributeList.push({
    Name: "phone_number",
    Value: phoneNumber,
  });
  attributeList.push({
    Name: "given_name",
    Value: firstName,
  });
  attributeList.push({
    Name: "family_name",
    Value: lastName,
  });
  const command = new SignUpCommand({
    ClientId: clientId,
    Username: email,
    Password: password,
    // SecretHash: generateHash(email),
    UserAttributes: attributeList,
  });
  const response = await client.send(command);
  
  return {
    ...response,
    // ...addUserToGroupResponse
  };
};
const loginUser = async (email, password) => {
  const command = new InitiateAuthCommand({
    AuthFlow: "USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
    ClientId: clientId,
    AuthParameters: {
      USERNAME: email,
      PASSWORD: password,
      
      // SECRET_HASH: generateHash(email)
    },
    
  });
  const response = await client.send(command);
  return response;
};
```

I now want to add log in with Google/Facebook/Apple but I don't see any documentation about how to add this logic to my backend. Everywhere I look people mention amplify in React frontend to do this but is there a way to implement it in my backend and simply make an axios post request to authenticate with Google?